# Show truffle migration history

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, history

What is the best way to show truffles migration history or at least the last successful step. Something similar what I see when I do `truffle migrate`:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x4724cf1e4bd9ce7323f837199d7bb0c71e36e7a0ebb1758f03d42814a6df18a2

  Migrations: 0xcfde951064e454bc5b1aeecc9d47745046b953a6

Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x46a6e8551dd37bf5c3354ce75da29b4cfd8d2cdeb14491bf25d7ada82630d4b4
Saving artifacts...

Running migration: 2_deploy_mycontracts.js

  Deploying MyToken...
  ... 0xc6cfb8617f3a8a75b9a1b6eb95d62066e1e4c4b2ba45f0be616ade7ed3e67f32
  MyToken: 0x2678b1f2c7d9c13279802bec54ee4284f7b736cc

  Deploying AnotherContract...
  ... 0xe54a6edc72d606da2d80f28022bb35cc6a393f4014549c5d1f7c2f614fc88ea8
  AnotherContract: 0x9f2a1cc604b86e75b88dd302be4bb0d66dcdd13e
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK truffle is only writing to stdout/err. So you'll need to redirect the output to a log file. But on the other hand, you also want to see it on stdout. If you're working with linux/macos you can use tee to achieve this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout